# Accessing the base list of a Linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a query that looks like this:

```
var tournamentMatches = community.Tournaments.
    SelectMany(x => x.Rounds.
    SelectMany(y =>  y.Matches)).Where(j => j.Away.Members.Count > 0).
    Select(t =>  new TeamLeagueMatch()
    {
        HomeParticipantId = t.HomeParticipant,
        PlayedOn = t.PlayedOn,
        Result = t.Result,                               
    }).ToList();
```

I'm wanting to access the base part of the list, to get the name of the tournament, so below `Result = t.Result` I'd like to be able to put:

```
 Name = x.Name
```

However, it doesn't recognise the x variable at this level.  Is there an easy way to get my name property without resorting to long involved foreach loops?

The classes look this:

```
public class Tournament
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<TournamentRound> Rounds { get; set; }
}

public class TournamentRound
{
    public DateTime? PlayBy { get; set; }
    public IList<Match> Matches { get; set; }
}

public class Match
{
    public MatchResult Result { get; set; }
    public MatchSide Home { get; set; }
    public MatchSide Away { get; set; }
}

public class MatchSide 
{
    public IList<string> Members { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand where exactly in your code you try to access `x.Name` ?=!

Comment: If you use query syntax you'll have no such problem.

Comment: x is related to community.Tournaments, so the first part of the query: community.Tournaments.SelectMany(x => x.Rounds... etc

Comment: Ivan could you elaborate what the query syntax would look like? I've never used it.

Comment: [Query syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx) shouldn't be necessary, since the compiler changes it to method syntax anyway, therefore anything possible using query syntax must be possible using method syntax.

Comment: @MatthewWatson True, but query syntax supports transparent identifiers, which make the above task quite **easy** compared to intermediate anonymous type projections and non naturally named accessors needed by the method syntax. It's similar to say not using `foreach` because the compiler changes it to `GetEnumerator`, `MoveNext` and `Current`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using query syntax:

```
 var tournamentMatches = (from tournament in community.Tournaments
                from round in tournament.Rounds
                from match in round.Matches
                where match.Away.Members.Count > 0
                select new TeamLeagueMatch
                {
                    HomeParticipantId = match.HomeParticipant,
                    PlayedOn = match.PlayedOn,
                    Result = match.Result,
                    Name = tournament.Name
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: I think just using query syntax is enough here (without needing the `let`) - `tournament` will still be in scope by the time you get to the `select`.

Answer (score 1):

The multi from statement will be translated in to this

```
community.      
SelectMany(t => t.Rounds, (turnament, round) => new { turnament, round }).
SelectMany(tr => tr.round.Matches, (tr, match) => new {tr.turnament,tr.round,match }).
Where(trm=>trm.match.Away.Members.Count>0).
Select(trm => new TeamLeagueMatch()
                   {
                      HomeParticipantId = trm.match.HomeParticipant,
                      PlayedOn = trm.match.PlayedOn,
                      Result = trm.match.Result,
                      Name = trm.turnament.Name
                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: Looks good, but it doesn't let me put 'Select' on y.Matches.Select.  The only option it gives me is 'SelectMany'

Comment: Strange I tested with the class you put in the sample and it compiled?